# How to concatenate multiple strings in android for url types

Tags: android, android-intent

i have a develop an app to searching and play the video, in my project ive face a diffculty to pass the path of the searched video to video play activity. when i put actual path of the video directly in to the player activity it palys the video but if i get the video name from the intent and then i convert it as path of that video. it dont get paly. and my program does not show any error
i cant get the intent data that i passed from the first activity it shows "null" when i set that data into the textview pls help me to recover this problem

HERE IS MY FIRST ACTIVITY

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity  {

EditText et;
Button bt;
String filename;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.firstscreen);

     et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);


     filename = et.getText().toString();

     bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

     final Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
     i.putExtra("text_label", filename);



     bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             startActivity(i);

        }

     });
     }
```

}

AND THIS IS MY SECOND ACTIVITY TO THE VIDEO PLAYER

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implementsSurfaceHolder.Callback{

  MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
  urfaceView surfaceView;
  SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
  boolean pausing = false;;

 String uriString;

 String stringPaths= "/sdcard/video/";
 String stringPath;

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button buttonPlayVideo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.playvideoplayer);
    Button buttonPauseVideo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pausevideoplayer);

     Intent i = getIntent();
     uriString = i.getStringExtra("text_label");
      stringPath  = stringPaths+uriString+".3gp";

     getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setFixedSize(176, 300);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

  buttonPlayVideo.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

 @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     pausing = false;

   if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    }

   mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);

   try {
 mediaPlayer.setDataSource(stringPath);
  mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
    }

     mediaPlayer.start();


    }});

 buttonPauseVideo.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(pausing){
 pausing = false;
 mediaPlayer.start();
 }
else{
 pausing = true;
     mediaPlayer.pause();
   }
    }});

   }



@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
int height) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

    @Override
     public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
   }
```

so here is my questions 
1. did i pass the intent corectly to the second activity.
2. how should i concatenate that get intent data with the file path string.

pls help me
im struck with this.

Comment: I don't see any obvious problem.  Have you tried logging out and comparing the prepared string vs the string you passed in to the dataSource call?  Also, you should consider looking at the Android VideoView, it's a bit easier to use than the SurfaceViews

Comment: i use video view but it doesnt play my video pls suggest any link to use video view in my app

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in onCreate method - your intent is created each time the activity is created but not shown to the user so the TextView is empty.

Try to put extra to the intent in onClick - and there you can also check if textView is empty. It will be something like this:

```
 bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
         filename = et.getText().toString();
         Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
         i.putExtra("text_label", filename);
         startActivity(i);
    }
 });
```

You can still create intent in the onCreate method's scope keeping it final but assigning extra in the onClick method.

Also consider that et.getText() can be null and et.getText().toString() can generate NullPointerException, so I'd rather extracted it to the Editable variable and check if it's not null and not empty.

Comment: I am glad that your problem is void now :) Please, accept the answer!